# why does powershell veriable output incorrectly

Tags: string, powershell

I'm attempting to create a quick script that'll automate the generic parts of an email procedure. The script works entirely how it's intended to. However, it isn't outputting any subject to the email. In the $body of the output, it's outputting correctly, though. Why is it that the program runs correctly but won't add to the subject?

The only error output from this is the following:

> param : The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$type = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the ticket type", " ")

param(
    $body = "Hi

Could this ticket please be updated; 

$Ticketnumber - $company 
$Timerange - $Contacttype 
$Bodymessage - $type

Thanks,
"
)  

# Functions

function Send-Email (
    $recipientEmail = "email",
    $subject = $(Throw "Ticket" + $type),
    $body
) {
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $mail.Recipients.Add("email")
    $mail.Subject = $subject
    $mail.Body = $body   # For HTML encoded emails
    $mail.Send()
    Write-Host "Email sent!"
}
```

Comment: Yes it seems to do what you programmed it to do. So what did you put in, what did you get out, and what id you *expect* to get out?

Comment: @nvoigt it doesn't add the subject, I re-opened the script and it was outputting what it was remembering however now it simply doesn't add to the subject.

Comment: You can't put a `Param()` declaration just anywhere in your code. It MUST be at the beginning of a script or function.

Comment: What you've posted here really isn't enough to tell what's going on well enough to be able to tell you how to properly fix it. Where are the variables embedded in `$body` defined? How the is the `Send-Email` function called?  In `$subject = $(Throw "Ticket" + $type)`, `$type` is likely out of scope. Have you read `Get-Help about_Scopes`?

Comment: I've removed $subject and when directly with $mail.Subject = ("Ticket - " + $type) - this seems to have resolved the issue though if i'm honest I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you have `param` in there, and a function. By wrapping `$subject` in a function, you're making it inaccessible to the actual sending of the email. In addition, I'd recommend using `Send-MailMessage` instead if possible. Either way though, remove the param and the function and you should be good to go.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$type = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the ticket type", " ")


$body = "Hi 

Could this ticket please be updated; 

$ticketnumber - $company 
$timerange - $contacttype 
$bodymessage - $type

Thanks,
"

$recipientEmail = "email"
$subject = "Ticket" + $type


{
$outlook = New-Object -comObject  Outlook.Application 
$mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0) 
$mail.Recipients.Add("email") 
$mail.Subject = $subject 
$mail.Body = $body   # For HTML encoded emails  
$mail.Send() 
Write-Host "Email sent!"
}
```

**EDIT**

Can you please try replacing the whole Outlook block with `Send-MailMessage` and see if you have the same issue?

`Send-MailMessage -to "email" -from "OtherEmail" -Subject $subject -Body $body -SmtpServer "SMTPServer"`

Comment: This does seem to be a much better approach indeed, I've converted over to this however output remains the same: https://gyazo.com/f3a5d3354d10af2316eec27cea23dd7e - my understanding is $mail.Subject = $subject  should deal with adding to the subject - subject being defined with "Ticket" + $type but still remains empty.

Comment: I just added another piece to the answer. Can you please try that and let me know? Doing it this way works for me no problems. :)

Comment: "Send-MailMessage : The remote name could not be resolved: 'SMTPServer'" - Possible module missing on my end? - Send-Email -recipientEmail $email -subject $subject -body $body changed ti Send-MailMessage -to "email" -from "OtherEmail" -Subject $subject -Body $body -SmtpServer "SMTPServer"

Comment: You have to put your companies SMTP server there. Another option might be to remove the curly brackets from around your original Outlook block, but both of the methods I've listed work on my end.

Comment: Found the server, unable to connect however : Send-MailMessage : Unable to connect to the remote server. Found server using NSlookup, i believe this is the server needed to connect.

Comment: Might be a permissions issue, but make sure you used the FQDN of the SMTP server. Going back to the original Outlook block, did you try removing the braces?

Comment: Yes, Originally using Send-Email -recipientEmail $email -subject $subject -body $body  sending wasn't an issue. This is the reason no subject is being added to the mail?

Comment: I've removed $subject and when directly with $mail.Subject = ("Ticket - " + $type) - this seems to have resolved the issue though if i'm honest I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = $(Throw "Ticket" + $type)
```

should read

```
$subject = "Ticket" + $type
```

Comment: I've edited to this, output is exactly the same - no subject

Comment: I've removed $subject and when directly with $mail.Subject = ("Ticket - " + $type) - this seems to have resolved the issue though if i'm honest I have no idea why